# ColdFusion JDBC Connection String Issue

Tags: jdbc, coldfusion

I'm trying to setup a 3rd party JDBC driver as a datasource, but it appears to not matter what I put in the Connection String field in CFAdmin, it doesn't seem to use it at all.

```
User=user@account.com;Password=!password;
```

Errors out with `Login failed: You must provide a user and password to login.`

I tried putting random text into the Connection String field expecting it to error out, but nothing happened either.

I was wondering if I was entering the data wrong (I also tried the entire connection string with the jdbc:, but that did not work either) or if there was some way to verify the entire connection string that ColdFusion was trying to use.

I'm not trying anything special inside of my cfquery tag: `<cfquery name="output" datasource="mySource">` so that should not be the issue. I can get around the user/password issue by hard-coding these values in the cfquery tag, but there is a 3rd key that I need to provide as a connection value as well.

The issue shouldn't be with my connection string, because the following worked with pure Java:

`conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mydriver:User=user;Password=password;AccessToken=accessToken;");`

.

An interesting addition...ColdFusion appears to not care at ALL what is at the end of my URL as long as the beginning is correct...

`jdbc:mydriverrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr:`

gives the username/password error. Whereas:

`jdbc:mydriveer:`

gives me an "unable to find driver" error.

.

edit: I also experience this issue in CF9, so it isn't just an issue with CF10

.

edit: I'm able to set the username/password inside of the CF datasource settings, but it still appears to be ignoring anything I put at the end of the URL or in the connection strings (AccessToken is still needed).

.

edit: I tried a DSNless connection: http://www.hostmysite.com/support/cfusion/dsnless/ but it behaves similarly to CFAdmin, whereas it is ignoring the connection string portion.

`Login failed: You must provide a user and password to login.`

..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `DataSource` implementation you are using, but DataSources have their own javabeans-style properties, including `user` and `password`. You will probably need to use those instead of providing a properties with the URL.

Comment: I am using the properties inside of the Connection String, including them wht the URL was how I did it in pure Java to verify that it worked.